# Weird issue with MaterialCardView

Tags: java, android, xml, materialcardview

I'm trying to make a rounded shape like this :

[image]

The code below works great on a device with 6.7" as screen size.

```
   <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/resultHolder"
        android:layout_width="232dp"
        android:layout_height="376dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="15"
        android:outlineProvider="background"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="120dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/green_neon"
        app:strokeWidth="6dp">


        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/thumbnail"
            android:id="@+id/resultImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

But when I test the app on device with 5.1" as screen size. I get this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting

```
android:layout_width="232dp"
android:layout_height="376dp"
```

which are fixed values when you put `app:cardCornerRadius="120dp"` which is very high it does not get the space to complete it's 120dp radius on a smaller screen..
Use a background drawable or a different solution. This solution will work perfectly only in the 6.7 inch screen that you have and only that

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however, using `android:outlineProvider="none"` makes the shape rounded perfectly in the small screen, but the `imageView` is not rounded, I think the issue is with the `imageView` rather than the `MaterialCardView`

Comment: Alright..scaletype as center crop . Maybe that is distorting the image.. Since the reason remains that it's not getting the space accoriding to the dimentions as you have fixed values

Comment: I've fixed the issue by using a custom RoundedImageView along with MaterialCardView, thank you again for your help